# With Irssi you can /rmreconns to abort timed-out conections. Is there a command to force it to reconnect *now*?

Tags: irssi

I have an IRC server running on my personal computer, and I use an ssh tunnel to connect to it from a more reliable box (i.e. one where my daughter can't reach the power button).

Occasionally the power will be cut from my box, causing the connection to drop. Irssi tries to reconnect to that server after a specified period - alternatively I can `/rmreconns` to stop it from reconnecting, and then manually `/connect` again. When I run `/connect` it seems to connect to my server *twice*. Once with the manual connection, and once when it reconnects on its own.

I find it really annoying to do `/rmreconns`, and then `/connect localhost port`

Is there a command I can run to force it to reconnect **now**? I haven't been able  to find one, but I may be looking in the wrong place.

Comment: That's for that reference to `/rmreconns`, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `/reconnect`.  I use a similar configuration to you, and use this all the time.

Comment: It seems like that only reconnects the active server or servers that are currently connected...

Comment: It takes an argument, for the server network you want to reconnect.  Or you can hit `ctrl-X` to switch to the network you want to reconnect.

Comment: If you pass `ALL` it will reconnect to all servers that are in the reconnect queue (the ones that would be removed if you ran `/rmreconns`)